# listen to value change by another script

Tags: javascript, jquery

So in My web app, there is a field with id `#billing_address_1`. user can input their address in this field, and also can select a value from its autocomplete, keep in mind this is not built in browser autocomplete.

in another js file there is an event listener which is listen to any changes to `#billing_address_1`. the script is:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#billing_address_1').on('change paste keyup blur', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

the script working good when user type in their address, however when user select a value from the autocomplete, instead of print a selected value from autocomplete it's print an old value. ex. user type in `band` and then select `bandung` from autocomplete, it print `band` in the js console.

Autocomplete code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('<div id="addr-find">').appendTo('body').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'display':'none',
        'top':'0',
        'left':'0',
        'padding':'10px',
        'background': '#fff',
        'box-shadow':'0 0 2px #ccc',
        'max-height': '250px',
        'overflow-y':'auto'
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(e){
        if($(e.target).parents('#addr-find').length == 0 && e.target.id != 'billing_address_1'){
            $('#addr-find').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#billing_address_1').on('focus', function(){
        $('#addr-find').show();
    });

    $('#billing_address_1').on('keyup', function(){
        var data = {
            action: 'search_address',
            addr: $(this).val()
        }, $this = $(this), borderWidth = ($this.css('borderWidth').length) > 0 ? parseInt($this.css('borderWidth').replace(/[^\d]/g, '')):0;

        var top = $this.offset().top + $this.innerHeight() + borderWidth;
        var left = $this.offset().left;
        var width = $this.innerWidth() + borderWidth

        console.log(top, $this.innerHeight(), borderWidth);

        $('#addr-find').css({
            "top": top,
            "left": left,
            "width": width
        }).html('Loading...').show();

        $.post(AddrFind.ajaxurl, data, function(response){
            if(response.length > 0){
                lis = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                    lis.push('<li style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:5px;margin-bottom:5px"><a href="#" class="list-addr">'+response[i]+'</a></li>');
                }

                $('#addr-find').html('<ul style="margin:0;list-style:none">'+lis.join('')+'</ul>').show();

                $('body').off('click').on('click', '#addr-find a', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $this.val($(this).text());
                    $('#addr-find').hide();
                });
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Comment: Show the actual code that's causing the problem. If the code for the autocomplete is the problem then show it, we can't help with what you've given.

Comment: the point is, how to listen to input field which is change dynamicly by ajax or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

What actually happens here is you are printing the value of the input field before autocomplete assigns the value to the field. If you can provide the autocomplete code here, we can suggest an answer.
I know this is a comment, but i have no option but to comment here as i get comment right only on reaching a 50 reputation milestone.

EDIT HERE:

This is a copied code from an old post. but this should create an obj protoype watch event. 
Using watch Rather than change event should solve your problem

```
if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch", {
          enumerable: false
        , configurable: true
        , writable: false
        , value: function (prop, handler) {
            var
              oldval = this[prop]
            , newval = oldval
            , getter = function () {
                return newval;
            }
            , setter = function (val) {
                oldval = newval;
                return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
            }
            ;

            if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
                Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                      get: getter
                    , set: setter
                    , enumerable: true
                    , configurable: true
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

// object.unwatch
if (!Object.prototype.unwatch) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "unwatch", {
          enumerable: false
        , configurable: true
        , writable: false
        , value: function (prop) {
            var val = this[prop];
            delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
            this[prop] = val;
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks to this guy's post in Github 
https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

Comment: by using your hint "before autocomplete assigns the value". i added setTimeout in `console.log` stuf. working great.

Comment: Using set timeout in such case is a bad practice. I blive. Try using this watch